# $M$ contains all ordinals

Tags: set-theory

I would like to prove the following claim: If M is a transitive class such that Def(M) $\subseteq$ M, then $On^M$= $On$.

My own proof would start like this:

Proof. Since "x is an ordinal " is absolute ($\Delta_0$), we have $On^M\subseteq On$. Suppose that   $On^M \neq On$. Let $\alpha$ be the least ordinal in $On - On^L$. Then we will proof the following:

Claim: $\alpha = On^M$

Could someone help me to finish the proof ?

Comment: Are you having trouble with $\alpha \subset On^M$ or $On^M \subset \alpha?$

Comment: $On^M\subseteq \alpha$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: So $\alpha \not \in On^M.$ If $\beta>\alpha,$ can $\beta \in On^M?$ Remember the definition of transitivity.